# Regarding multiple image upload using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a component for image upload as you can see in attachment.

[image]

As you can see user can upload 4 images and all images will be saved to server folder using PHP. That is what i already did.

Now the issue is i want allow user to select any image and set it as primary. I already have fields like image1, image2, image3, image4 in database.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a php mysql question , the qty of num images to upload is handled on javascript , please take a look on documentation : 
[dropzone config options](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-maxFiles)

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
maxFilesize: 2, // MB
maxFiles: NUM OF FILES
accept: function(file, done) {
if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
  done("Naha, you don't.");
}
 else { done(); }
 }
};
```

However i recommend to check it on server side also , don't trust only in client side actions.

Comment: I have added mockup to explain my issue in detail.